# Can't create sqlite db on production machine

Tags: database, sqlite, connection-string, production

I have a program that works correctly on my computer in Debug mode.

When my program start he create a `Sqlite data base` file if not exists.

This is ok on my computer.

I create a setup version for production version. The program setup **is ok**.

But when I start the program (*.exe*) my db file is not created.

This is the connection string I used :

```
 static string dbDirectopry = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    static string dbName = "MySqliteDb.db";

    static string Connexion = Path.Combine(dbDirectopry, @"MySociety\MyApplication\" + dbName);
```

Comment: Show the code that creates that directory.

Comment: @Paintbox Please help to contribute to the community by providing an answer to this question if you've resolved it.

Comment: Also, please move the update from the answer you did post into this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for your help,

this is the code that create db.

```
public static void CreateDb(string path)
    {
        SqLiteHelper sqlite = new SqLiteHelper(path);
        try
        {
            User.CreateTable();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

Normaly if the file doesn't exists he is automaticaly created.

If I try my application in Debug mode with Visual Studio my db is created and I can write into.

But when I deploy my application it doesn't work anymore.
My problem is is there any special directory (for windows) to create de db file?